# Display list of datas from sharedprefrence to text widget flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am saving some list of data to Sharedprefrence and tried to call the data from saved sharedprefrence and it returs all the values i have saved,then i tried to show data from sharedprefrence to a text widget but it shows null,

i need something like,if i have t text widgets how do pass data to those two widget let's say ₹575  and TWA Cap

Retrieving the data from sharedprfrence

```
List<String> listdata=[];
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPrefrence().getCartItem().then((data) async{
      listdata = data;
      print(listdata);
    });
  }
```

this what i am geting from the sharedprefrence

```
[TWA Cap, ₹575, M, Red]
```

trying to shows te data to text widget (Whole widget)

```
     Widget CoupensLists() {
   
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 1,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    
            return Row(

              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 10,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 350,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 50,
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Image.network("image"),
                                    /* decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: Image.,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      ),
                                    ),*/
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                 "Prodcut name",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                Text("Prodcut name",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 4),
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 80,
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            SvgPicture.asset(
                                              'assets/images/bg_price_btn_black.svg',
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Price"
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 12),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Stack(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SvgPicture.asset(
                                          'assets/images/bg_boon_btn_red.svg',
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Book Now",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 12),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                           
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you getting an error? or the text is just not showing your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use in initail function    
setState(() {
    listdata = data;
});
```

then

```
Widget CoupensLists() {

return SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  child: Container(
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

        return Row(

          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 350,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 80,
                                child: Image.network("image"),
                                /* decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: Image.,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  ),
                                ),*/
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                            listdata.length!=0? listdata[0]:"",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text( listdata.length!=0? listdata[1]:"",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 4),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 80,
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SvgPicture.asset(
                                          'assets/images/bg_price_btn_black.svg',
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                          child: Text(
                                             listdata.length!=0? listdata[2]:"",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 12),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SvgPicture.asset(
                                      'assets/images/bg_boon_btn_red.svg',
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                      child: Text(
                                        listdata.length!=0? listdata[3]:"",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 12),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                       
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),``
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: This prints out all data into single text, i need something like,if i have t text widgets how do pass data to those two widget let's say `₹575 ` and  `TWA Cap` @Johny Saini

Comment: Can you please show me your code what you want .You have list you can get data from list set into local variables than use these local variable in all widget.

Comment: You can get data from list using any loop like forEach.

Comment: Post your widget code  I will change it according to your need.

Comment: in the place of  `Product name` i need `TWA Cap` in the place of `Price` i need `₹575`." @Johny Saini

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<String> listdata=[];
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPrefrence().getCartItem().then((data) async{      
      setState(() {
        listdata = data;
      });
    });
  }
```

You're getting this because you didn't upated your screen after changing the listdata variable

Comment: i am getting the data no problem with that.i need something like,if i have t text widgets how do pass data to those two widget let's say `₹575 ` and  `TWA Cap` @Vitor